# (( COUNT++ )) -> "COUNT++: not found" in shell script

Tags: shell

```
#!/bin/sh
INTERVAL=1
COUNT=0
while [ $COUNT -le 9 ]
do
    (( COUNT++ ))
    sleep $INTERVAL
    echo "count is $COUNT"
done
```

On execution.

```
$ sh ascript 
ascript: 9: COUNT++: not found
count is 0
ascript: 9: COUNT++: not found
count is 0
ascript: 9: COUNT++: not found
count is 0
ascript: 9: COUNT++: not found
count is 0
ascript: 9: COUNT++: not found
count is 0
ascript: 9: COUNT++: not found
count is 0
ascript: 9: COUNT++: not found
count is 0
ascript: 9: COUNT++: not found
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably want `#!/bin/bash` rather than `#!/bin/sh` at the top if you want to use bash-specific operations.

Your script does work fine here on my Mac, where `sh` is really just `bash`.  If your `sh` is a real one you might not be so lucky.

Comment: Arithmetic substitution is POSIX, not just `bash`.

Comment: So maybe OP's `sh` isn't fully POSIX then - what's the difference?

Comment: @geekosaur I don't think the naked `(( ))` construct is POSIX, though `$(( ))` is. For example, `dash` chokes on OP's script in exactly the same way.

Comment: The naked `(())` is definitely listed in the `bash` man page.

Comment: On my machine, `bash ascript` and `sh ascript` work just fine but `dash ascript` fails as OP describes.

Comment: @Clueless, is `sh` an alias of `bash` on your machine?

Comment: Yes, `/bin/sh` points to `/bin/bash`. Bash has some special behavior when called as `sh`, so it's worth mentioning anyways.

Answer (score 8):

`(( ))` would be a nested subshell (two of them, in fact) with an invocation of a command `COUNT++`.  You want the `$(( ))` arithmetic substitution mechanism; but that will actually *substitute*, so you either want to hide it in a comment or use an increment that involves a substitution.

```
: $(( COUNT++ )) # : is a shell comment
```

or

```
COUNT=$(( $COUNT + 1 ))
```

Comment: OP's script works fine for me here with `bash`, no `$` required.

Comment: @CarlNorum you're right. Thanks geekosaur for telling me about this.

Comment: : does not begin a comment; it is a no-op, in this case taking a single argument.  Comments are indicated by #.  (But +1 anyway)

Comment: `:` was a shell comment back before `#` comments were borrowed from `csh`.

Comment: It wasn't a true comment even then; you just didn't *have* a true comment character at all. If it's parsed as code and executed -- if it updates `$?` or prints something when run with `set -x` -- it ain't a comment.

Comment: Mark for usage of `:`

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/bash
COUNT=0;
while [ $COUNT -le 9 ] ; 
do sleep 1; 
(( COUNT++ )) ; 
echo $COUNT ; 
done
```

It's a better way to write this script. And I recommend you to run your script as follow:
`./script.sh`
or
`bash ./script.sh`

If you don't have bash, use this way:

```
#!/bin/sh
ENV=1
while [ $ENV -le 10 ]
do
sleep 1
echo $ENV
ENV=`expr $ENV + 1`
done
```

Answer (score 2):

From `help for`:

> ```
> for ((: for (( exp1; exp2; exp3 )); do COMMANDS; done
>     Arithmetic for loop.
>
>     Equivalent to
>         (( EXP1 ))
>         while (( EXP2 )); do
>                 COMMANDS
>                 (( EXP3 ))
>         done
>     EXP1, EXP2, and EXP3 are arithmetic expressions.  If any expression is
>     omitted, it behaves as if it evaluates to 1.
>
>
>     Exit Status:
>     Returns the status of the last command executed.
> ```

Don't forget to execute it using **`bash`**.

Answer (score 0):

This: `(( COUNT++ ))` doesn't do what you want.

Change to: `let "COUNT++"`

See: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ops.html for more on arithmetic operations in bash.

And, to use bash, use `#!/bin/bash` rather than `#!/bin/sh`

Comment: This works. (had to switch from sh to bash, as let was not defined in sh)

Comment: `let` and `(( ))` are literally identical in `bash`.  The man page even says so:  "`(( ))`... This is exactly equivalent to let 'expression'."

Comment: @yayu It was switching to Bash, not switching to `let`, that fixed your problem; `let` is the same as `(( ))` in Bash, but neither of those are defined in POSIX. If you are on a Debian based system (Debian, Ubuntu, Mint, or one of the many other varieties), `sh` is probably Dash, which is a minimalist shell that doesn't support much beyond what POSIX requires.

Comment: Please avoid pointing folks at the ABS as a reference -- it's woefully undermaintained and has a history of showcasing bad practices in its examples. The bash-hackers' wiki has [an excellent page on arithmetic expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arith_expr), as does [the Wooledge wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression).

Answer (score 0):

mine was giving me this error just because I tried execute it with sh (ex. sh `code.sh`), but when I did `./code.sh` it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Changing from `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash` worked like a dream for me when incrementing a variable using `count++` to sequentially rename files.

The original script starting `#!/bin/sh` worked fine in Fedora but not in Kali (Debian) when I also got

> count++: not found

Simply replacing `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash` fixed this fine - presumably because the default shell in Kali/Debian is not bash. This is consistent with my having to change the default shell when configuring Kali which was using dash I think.